Does a Lipschitz continuous pdf necessarily have bounded variation?
Does a probability density function $f(x)$ that satisfies the Lipschitz condition  on the entire real line $\mathbb{R}$ have bounded variation?
Undoubtedly, this holds on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.
Def 1. Lipschitz condition on $\mathbb{R}$: $\forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R},|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \leq C |x_1 - x_2|$ for some constant $C > 0.$
Def 2.
The variation of $f$ on $[a, b]$ corresponding to a partition $P = \big\{x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n\big\},$
$V^P(f):=\sum_{i=1}^{n} |f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})|.$
Obviously, if $Q$ is a refinement of $P$, then $V^P(f) \leq V^Q(f)$. If the set $\big\{V^P(f) : P \text{ is a partition of } [a, b]\big\}$ is bounded, then $f$ is called a function of bounded variation on $[a, b]$ and $V^{[a, b]}(f) := \sup_P V^P(f)$ is the total variation of $f$ on $[a, b]$.
Def 3.
For the entire $\mathbb{R}$,if the set $\big\{V^{[a,b]}(f) : [a, b] \text{ is a bounded interval on } \mathbb{R} \big\}$ is bounded, then $f$ is called a function of bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}$ and $V_{\mathbb{R}}(f):= \sup_{[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}} \big\{V^{[a,b]}(f)\big\}$ is the total variation of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.


Some probability density functions (pdfs) have bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}$ but do not satisfy the Lipschitz condition. For instance,

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{\pi} \sqrt{1 - x^2}, & \text{for } x \in [-1, 1], \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Conversely, a pdf $f(x)$ ($f(x)\ge 0,\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(x)dx=1$) satisfies the Lipschitz condition $\mathbb{R}$,then we may get that $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|$ is bounded and $\lim_{x\rightarrow  \pm \infty}f(x)=0.$ That said, I have a gut feeling it might have infinite total variation on $\mathbb{R}$. I’m trying to find some counterexamples to back this up! 1D Gaussian density function is Lipschitz continuous but it also have bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}$.


Have you tried using the Lipschitz condition in the definition of variation?

You need to try some basic stuff first.

@ Pranay From the Lipschitz condition, $f $ is absolutely continuous and there exists $ M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ |f'(x)| \leq M $ almost everywhere. However, this is not enough to ensure that the total variation is finite.

You haven't given the definition of "total variation on $\mathbb{R}$", only on a bounded interval.

But consider a function like $h(x)(1 + \sin(g(x))$ where $h$ is integrable and $g$ grows very rapidly.

Your gut feeling that "Lipschitz does not imply bounded variation" is correct as the below example illustrates.
Let $x_0=0$ and $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k$ for $n>0$. Consider the function $g:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ given by $g(x) = 1-|2x-1|$, whose graph is a triangle of base $1$ and height $1$. Now define
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac1n g(n(x-x_{n-1})), &x_{n-1} \le x \le x_n, \text{for } n\ge1,
\\
f(-x),&x\le0.
\end{cases}
$$
Basically, $f(x)$ is a train of triangles whose heights and bases decrease as $1/n$ as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$. Clearly, the area under $f(x)$ is the sum of areas of all the triangles, which goes as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^2} < \infty$. Moreover, $f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous because $|f'(x)| = 1$ at every $x$, except at $x \in \{\pm x_n:n\ge 0\}$, a measure zero set, where it is still continuous. However, consider the partition $P=\{x_0,\frac{x_0+x_1}2,x_1,\frac{x_1+x_2}2,\ldots,x_n\}$ of $[x_0,x_n]$. The variation of $f$ on this partition is twice the sum of heights of all the triangles in this interval, i.e.,
$$
V^P(f) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( |f(x_k)-f(\tfrac{x_k+x_{k-1}}2)| + |f(\tfrac{x_k+x_{k-1}}2)-f(x_{k-1})| \right) = 2 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k.
$$
Clearly, as $n\rightarrow\infty$, this variation diverges.
